# Invoke Outlook with external application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, outlook, google-chrome-app, mailto

Please tell/help me if is it a possibility to integrate following features:

I have a CRM system, that I need to open in Chrome (system is compatible with this browser). System mostly is build from a fields (forms).

I also have outlook 2010.

The thing is, that I need to have a application that will send to the customer e-mail, based on template. I know that is "mailto" function.
Scenario 1: 
So I am on the website where I have Name of user and e-mail. 
I should click "Send e-mail" in this new one, external app. App should take that e-mail and name of the user and open new mail window in Outlook.

Scenario 2:
I would like to replay for clicked e-mail in Outlook, with a data from browser. 
So I should choose an e-mail, than I open website with a data that need to be take and put in mail. Next click button in an app, which open "replay to" option (below new mail it is a old e-mail).

How to take data from chrome to the external app? Maybe better is to create extension in Chrome?
I know that in Mozilla there is a mozrepl that give a possibility to send data for external app.

Could you help me, with that or give tips, how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest custom code

You already have Scenario 1 covered (with the mailto:  uri)

Scenario 2 is tricky - I am not sure how you would signal to Outlook to find the latest message with the Sender and Subject and Time and then send from there.  Maybe you can create an Outlook addin?

But, because of the Scenario 2 being tricky, I would just consider custom code (C#?).  Your code would have to send emails (easy with .Net), and also view the inbox for the messages to reply to.

Finally - if Custom Code is not the way, could you research a new programmable mail client that can handle your needs better?  I know there are a few that have a variety of features.

Answer (score 0):

You can't automate Outlook from Chrome. You can access the Outlook object model from Internet Explorer only. Chrome doesn't know anything about COM objects.

You may consider developing a server-side application where you can send emails. For example, it can be an ASP.NET page which can use System.Net.Mail namespace for sending/reading emails. You can display emails, replies and other information on the web page. If you need to connect to outlook.com mailbox you may consider using [Mail REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations).

Comment: This would be possible with a Chrome extension though, using [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to create some sort of COM proxy.

Comment: I developed  easy extension for chrome, but as you wrote, there is a problem with ActiveX: ActiveX Objet is not defined. I red about mailto function, but it is a probem with body. I need to have formatted e-mail. Can I please for help with this Native Messaging? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The MS Graph gives you access to mail. There is a property weblink on a mail item, which will open the item in web mail but it can't access archived mail.